# Python object attribute is another object, won't load using pickle.load(). What am I doing wrong?

Tags: python, object, pickle

I have an object:

```
class X():
    def __init__(self, a, b, c):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self.c = c
```

whose attribute c, is a of list objects (of a different kind):

```
class Y():
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
```

I pickle this as follows:

```
import pickle
pickle.dump(instance_of_class_X,open(dir, "wb"))
```

I load as follows:

```
import pickle
from some_library import X, Y # I import the two classes involved
pickle.load(open(dir,"rb"))
```

I get the following error:

> AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Y'

Not sure what to do, any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: where is the exception being raised?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Possibly you are falling victim to the need of `pickle` to have the class available via the same fully-qualified name as was originally used.  It would depend on what namespace X and Y are in when you originally create the object.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3363281/attributeerror-module-object-has-no-attribute-when-using-cpickle) and [this page](http://stefaanlippens.net/pickleproblem).

Comment: I think you are right. I had class X on the python file I ran, and class Y was inside of a function that I imported from a library (I did this for organization purposes). I copied and pasted the function I was importing to the python file I was running, and then pulled the class (Y) out of the function so that it was just like my other class X. Now it works. My code is a lot messier, but now it works. Wasn't aware of this subtlety in Python. Thanks Mate :)