# Error when using transform method from Latent Dirichlet Allocation after unpickling

Tags: python, machine-learning, anaconda, jupyter-notebook, spyder

I've trained a Latent Dirichlet Allocation model using sklearn. When I unpickle it, I then use countVectorizer to transform the document and then transform this instance using LDA in order to get the topic distribution but I'm getting the following error:

```
AttributeError: module '__main__' has no attribute 'tokenize'
```

Here is my code:

```
lda = joblib.load('lda_good.pkl')
#LDA trained model

tf_vect = joblib.load('tf_vectorizer_.pkl')
#vectorizer


texts = readContent('doc_name.pdf')

new_doc = tf_vect.transform(texts)

print(new_doc)

print(lda.transform(new_doc))
```

The thing is that the countVectorizer object unipickled is working fine and I can use `.transform` but when I try to then `.transform` using LDA's attribute it seems to refer to the tokenize function from the countvectorizer...
The function tokenize is defined ahead of the code, but I can't understant what does tokenize has to do with the transform method of Latent dirichlet Allocation. 
A weird thing is that all this code is working fine in jupyter notebook but not when i run it as a script..

All the code is in a single file. The model was trained using jupyter notebook and now I was trying to use the model within a script.

Here is the traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
Traceback (most recent call last):
File     "C:\Users\eduard.bermejo\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 106, in spawn_main
File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
File "C:\Users\eduard.bermejo\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 106, in spawn_main
exitcode = _main(fd)
File "C:\Users\eduard.bermejo\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 115, in _main
exitcode = _main(fd)
prepare(preparation_data)
File "C:\Users\eduard.bermejo\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 115, in _main
File "C:\Users\eduard.bermejo\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 226, in prepare
prepare(preparation_data)
File "C:\Users\eduard.bermejo\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 226, in prepare
_fixup_main_from_path(data['init_main_from_path'])
File "C:\Users\eduard.bermejo\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 278, in _fixup_main_from_path
Traceback (most recent call last):
Traceback (most recent call last):
_fixup_main_from_path(data['init_main_from_path'])
File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
run_name="__mp_main__")
File "C:\Users\eduard.bermejo\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 278, in _fixup_main_from_path
File "C:\Users\eduard.bermejo\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 254, in run_path
File "C:\Users\eduard.bermejo\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 106, in spawn_main
File "C:\Users\eduard.bermejo\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 106, in spawn_main
run_name="__mp_main__")
pkg_name=pkg_name, script_name=fname)
File "C:\Users\eduard.bermejo\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 254, in run_path
exitcode = _main(fd)
File "C:\Users\eduard.bermejo\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 96, in _run_module_code
exitcode = _main(fd)
File "C:\Users\eduard.bermejo\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 115, in _main
File "C:\Users\eduard.bermejo\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 115, in _main
pkg_name=pkg_name, script_name=fname)
prepare(preparation_data)
File "C:\Users\eduard.bermejo\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 226, in prepare
File "C:\Users\eduard.bermejo\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 96, in _run_module_code
mod_name, mod_spec, pkg_name, script_name)
_fixup_main_from_path(data['init_main_from_path'])
prepare(preparation_data)
File "C:\Users\eduard.bermejo\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
File "C:\Users\eduard.bermejo\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 278, in _fixup_main_from_path
mod_name, mod_spec, pkg_name, script_name)
File "C:\Users\eduard.bermejo\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 226, in prepare
exec(code, run_globals)
File "C:\Users\eduard.bermejo\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
File "C:\Users\eduard.bermejo\Documents\Machine learning\gestió documental\POC\program_POC.py", line 160, in <module>
run_name="__mp_main__")
_fixup_main_from_path(data['init_main_from_path'])
File "C:\Users\eduard.bermejo\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 254, in run_path
File "C:\Users\eduard.bermejo\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 278, in _fixup_main_from_path
exec(code, run_globals)
tf_vect = joblib.load('tf_vectorizer_.pkl')
pkg_name=pkg_name, script_name=fname)
File "C:\Users\eduard.bermejo\Documents\Machine learning\gestió    documental\POC\program_POC.py", line 160, in <module>
File "C:\Users\eduard.bermejo\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-  packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\numpy_pickle.py", line 459, in load
File "C:\Users\eduard.bermejo\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\runpy.py",  line 96, in _run_module_code
run_name="__mp_main__")
File "C:\Users\eduard.bermejo\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 254, in run_path
tf_vect = joblib.load('tf_vectorizer_.pkl')
obj = unpickler.load()
mod_name, mod_spec, pkg_name, script_name)
File "C:\Users\eduard.bermejo\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\numpy_pickle.py", line 459, in load
File  "C:\Users\eduard.bermejo\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\pickle.py", line 1039, in load
File "C:\Users\eduard.bermejo\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
pkg_name=pkg_name, script_name=fname)
File "C:\Users\eduard.bermejo\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 96, in _run_module_code
exec(code, run_globals)
File "C:\Users\eduard.bermejo\Documents\Machine learning\gestió documental\POC\program_POC.py", line 160, in <module>
obj = unpickler.load()
mod_name, mod_spec, pkg_name, script_name)
dispatch[key[0]](self)
File "C:\Users\eduard.bermejo\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\pickle.py", line 1039, in load
File "C:\Users\eduard.bermejo\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
File "C:\Users\eduard.bermejo\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\pickle.py", line 1334, in load_global
tf_vect = joblib.load('tf_vectorizer_.pkl')
exec(code, run_globals)
File "C:\Users\eduard.bermejo\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site- packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\numpy_pickle.py", line 459, in load
File "C:\Users\eduard.bermejo\Documents\Machine learning\gestió documental\POC\program_POC.py", line 160, in <module>
dispatch[key[0]](self)
File "C:\Users\eduard.bermejo\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\pickle.py", line 1334, in load_global
tf_vect = joblib.load('tf_vectorizer_.pkl')
obj = unpickler.load()
klass = self.find_class(module, name)
File "C:\Users\eduard.bermejo\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\numpy_pickle.py", line 459, in load
File "C:\Users\eduard.bermejo\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\pickle.py", line 1039, in load
File "C:\Users\eduard.bermejo\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\pickle.py", line 1388, in find_class
klass = self.find_class(module, name)
obj = unpickler.load()
File "C:\Users\eduard.bermejo\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\pickle.py", line 1388, in find_class
File "C:\Users\eduard.bermejo\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\pickle.py", line 1039, in load
dispatch[key[0]](self)
File "C:\Users\eduard.bermejo\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\pickle.py", line 1334, in load_global
return getattr(sys.modules[module], name)
AttributeError: module '__main__' has no attribute 'tokenize'
dispatch[key[0]](self)
File "C:\Users\eduard.bermejo\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\pickle.py", line 1334, in load_global
klass = self.find_class(module, name)
File "C:\Users\eduard.bermejo\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\pickle.py", line 1388, in find_class
return getattr(sys.modules[module], name)
AttributeError: module '__main__' has no attribute 'tokenize'
klass = self.find_class(module, name)
File "C:\Users\eduard.bermejo\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\pickle.py", line 1388, in find_class
return getattr(sys.modules[module], name)
AttributeError: module '__main__' has no attribute 'tokenize'
return getattr(sys.modules[module], name)
AttributeError: module '__main__' has no attribute 'tokenize'
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
File "C:\Users\eduard.bermejo\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 106, in spawn_main
File "C:\Users\eduard.bermejo\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 106, in spawn_main
exitcode = _main(fd)
exitcode = _main(fd)
```

It actually continues but I guess this will be enough because it starts some kind of loop.

Let me know if further information is needed.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Would you be able to share the directory structure of your project? Also please share the complete stacktrace so we can get a better idea of the line number it is pointing to

Comment: I updated with some more info. Thanks

Comment: Can you also paste the files and folders structure of the project please?

Comment: It is a single script named program_POC.py with the .pkl files within the same folder. There is no more structure. And all the imports are in the same script as well. Is this what you are asking for?

Comment: Got it. Yes. That is what I was asking for.

Comment: Did you try giving the full path of the pickeled object to `joblib.load` function? instead of just `tf_vectorizer_.pkl`? I would suggest you give `C:\Users\eduard.bermejo\Documents\Machine learning\gestió documental\POC\tf_vectorizer_.pkl` as the string to `joblib.load` and tell me if it works. Same applies to `lda_good.pkl`

Comment: Just tried it and I keep getting the same error.

Comment: Looking through [similar questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3363281/attributeerror-module-object-has-no-attribute-when-using-cpickle) on SO it shows there are pickling and unpickling issues. The code that you use to do `joblib.dump` is in a different directory from what I assume. So instead could you put that in the same directory as this program and pickle and unpickle again? The `__main__` is stored for the pickled directory and the unpickler tries to search for it when it runs.

Comment: Just trying it now, will let you know asap. Thanks

Comment: It did work! Thank you! Could you ellaborate your answer a litle bit on why this is happening and I will mark it as correct? Thank you so much.

Comment: Perfect! Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking through [similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3363281/attributeerror-module-object-has-no-attribute-when-using-cpickle) on SO it shows there are pickling and unpickling issues. The code that you use to do `joblib.dump` is in a different directory from what I assume. Instead could you put that in the same directory as this program and re-run the pickler and unpickler again? `__main__` is stored for the pickled directory and the unpickler tries to search for it when it runs.