# How Can I Python Function Export and Recall (Pickle,Joblib,Dump)?

Tags: python, function, pickle, joblib

```
def square(a):
    return a*a

joblib.dump(square,"squre.pkl")
joblib.load("square.pkl")(5)

output: 25
```

No problem when I call pickle in the same notebook. But when I open a different notebook(new notebook) and recall pickle, I get the following error. Please help for solution.

```
joblib.load("square.pkl")(5)
output=AttributeError: module '__main__' has no attribute 'square'
```

So my main problem is this. There is no problem recalling any model I saved (lgbm, kmeans etc). but I cannot recall a function I registered. Thanks

Comment: Functions are not pickled. Fully qualified names resolving to functions are pickled. Have a look at [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3363281/attributeerror-module-object-has-no-attribute-when-using-cpickle), especially Jeremy Brown's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3363546/4134674) as it contains a link to and an excerpt from the relevant documentation.

Comment: Thanks.i have a model (kmeans). I also have anomaly detection function (rulebase). I need to export both my model and my function, and then I can recall both smoothly. I'm not very good at programming. What do you suggest?

Answer (score 0):

**I solved it as follows**

```
 import dill as pickle
    def square(a):
        return a*a
    with open('square.pkl', 'wb') as file:
        pickle.dump(square,file)
```

*and open new notebook(python3)*

```
 with open('square.pkl', 'rb') as file:
    B = pickle.load(file)
    B(5)
    output:25
```